# Unhandled exception in CoreMessaging.dll during program shutdown

Tags: c++, windows, dll, sfml

I have a simple program that just displays a window, waits for a key press, and then exits. During shutdown, the app crashes, complaining about CoreMessaging.dll. Here is the sample code that has the issue:

```
sf::RenderWindow window;

void waitForKeyPress() {
  Event event;
  bool done = false;
  while (!done) {
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
      if (event.type == Event::KeyPressed) {
        done = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  // If I don't create the window, there's no crash.
  window.create(VideoMode::getDesktopMode(), "test", Style::Default); 
  waitForKeyPress();
  return 0; // Crashes upon returning.
}
```

This is the crash I get:

> Unhandled exception at 0x64260032 (CoreMessaging.dll) in game.exe: 0xC0000602:  A fail fast exception occurred. Exception handlers will not be invoked and the process will be terminated immediately.

The call stack doesn't seem particularly helpful

```
>   CoreMessaging.dll!64260032()    Unknown
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for CoreMessaging.dll] 
    [External Code] 
    InputHost.dll!5bb78a40()    Unknown
    [External Code]
```

The project was built using Visual Studio Community 2015. What is CoreMessaging.dll and why is it having an issue with this simple app that just shows a window and closes?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `sf::RenderWindow` but why is the window variable global?

Comment: Looking at [this page](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Window.php#acf67483dc21f08d65c8835b3889b41b2)  , you should try to put your `waitForKey` function inside `while (window.isOpen())`

Comment: It's a global because I wanted to throw together a really quick minimal example of the problem. The issue has nothing to do with the event handling or the global-ness of the window. I can remove that entirely and declare the window in the scope of main and the issue still occurs. Closing the window with window.close() after it's been opened doesn't resolve the issue either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is testing using a bugged, outdated build of Windows 10 that's affected by a bug now fixed with update KB4025342 (Win10 build 15063.483)

The bug fix summary that matches to your issue:
"**Addressed issue with CoreMessaging.dll that may cause 32-bit apps to crash on the 64-bit version of the Windows OS.**"

Read more about this issue here: [MSDN bugreport link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1008dfc3-223c-43e5-8f24-6d74b2872b75/new-crash-in-coremessagingdll-on-creators-update)

Please update your Windows build and check that the crash will be gone, then select my reply as answer if solved.

Comment: This sounds like a likely culprit. I'll give it a try when I'm at my computer. Thanks.

Comment: I must say you're a disgrace to stackoverflow if you fail to flag replies as answer after they solved your problem (which im sure it did). Find your solution and run since you already got what you needed :)

Comment: No need to be rude. Even after having windows check for updates it didn't go away - I think Microsoft decides when to roll out preview builds, and attempting to manually update my build didn't yield any results. As this was for a personal project and I have other things going on I haven't had time to see if a new update on my computer is available that sorts this out.